# How to deploy trained VGG-16 model, using python what could the best possible and free options

Tags: python, pytorch

I have trained a vgg16 model using transferlearning, now I want to deploy my trained model which is of size 520 Mbs, I want to opt for an easy method, either a web app or an android one, I have no prior development experience is their any possible way for deployment, also I don't want to go for a paid deployment option. For training purposes I have used Python and PyTorch framework. How may I deploy the model?

Comment: Google Cloud offers a $300 free trial, lasting 90 days. You could start a virtual machine there and use TorchServe to deploy your model.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a try